# Cron Expression for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

Is this the accurate cron expression to schedule my lambda function to run daily from Monday to Sunday at 4 am?

```
0 4 ? * MON-SUN *
```

Thnaks

Comment: Why not set up a cloud watch event? Check out this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Comment: Note that AWS uses UTC, so you'll need to mentally adjust times to your own timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Just varified this on AWS EventBridge, it is correct.